# Guardar estado de un Switch al salir del componente. Javascript. React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, web-components, state

Resulta que tengo un `<Switch />` como muestro a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la idea seria que cuando el usuario lo marque ya sea para un lado o para el otro (es un state **true**/**false**), al salir del componente, mejor dicho, al salir de la vista, regresar atrás y después al volver a entrar quede guardado el estado que dejó seleccionado por última vez.

Por lo que he investigado se puede hacer con *sessionStorage* y *localStorage*. Creo que en este caso es mejor **sessionStorage** ya que se trata de un cambio de vista. Por mi parte nunca he utilizado ninguno de los dos, estoy investigando la documentación y veo que en un momento hay que setearlo y en otro momento hacer un get, pero se me confunde a la hora de adaptarlo en mi código.

Puedo mostrar mi código del `<Switch />`:

```
    <Col span={2} style={{ marginTop: 15}}>
      <Switch 
        checkedChildren="C/Match" 
        unCheckedChildren="S/Match" 
        size="small" 
        checked={checked} 
        onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)} />
    </Col>
```

estaba probando realizar lo siguiente:

```
  sessionStorage.setItem('keyCheck', checked)
```

pero no me termina de convencer la parte del **'get'**. En realidad no me queda muy claro donde o en que parte tengo que hacer el 'set' y el 'get' dentro del componente/vista.

---

Antes del componente (localCheck fuera del componente):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro del componente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La parte del **get** se debe hacer cuando estes mostrando el elemento, ya sea cuando ha finalizado la carga del documento, ya sea por una llamada ajax posterior.  La forma habitual para que no de error es primero comprobar si esa clave exite en **sessionStorage**, y si existe entonces hacer el getItem de la clave y aplicar su valor al elemento cuando éste se muestre en el DOM.

Comment: Y con respecto al 'set', donde deberia hacerlo especificamente?. Consulta, tanto el 'set' como el 'get' van dentro del mismo componente? o sea, de la misma vista?

Comment: Te lo resumo tengo una vista/componente de Tabla y otra vista/componente de TablaId (con los detalles), dentro de la vista TablaId me gustaria guardar el estado, y cuando regrese a la vista de Tabla y vuelva a ingresar a otro TablaId me mantenga ese estado, me explico?

Comment: El **set** se hace siempre que se produzcan cambios en los valores del elemento por cualquier motivo, puede haber varios set, claro, si los eventos que producen esos cambios son distintos.  El donde ni idea, no se reactjs :-)

Comment: Si, a ver, eso que comentas es para lo que está pensando el localStorage/sessionStorage, para compartir información entre distintas páginas dentro de un mismo dominio y navegador (pues es el navegador quien conserva esos pares de clave/valor).  Tan solo debes usar la misma clave de sessionStorage en todas las páginas donde la necesites consultar o setear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar así.

```
//esta linea va fuera del componente, si no existe en la sessionStorage marca el valor por defecto que es true
//puedes ponerla como quieras.
const localCheck = sessionStorage.getItem("keyCheck") === null ? true : sessionStorage.getItem("keyCheck") === "true";


// Esto ya va dentro de tu componente.

const [checked, setChecked] = useState(localCheck);

function onChangeCheck(value, e){
  setChecked(value)
  sessionStorage.setItem("keyCheck", value)
}

  <Switch
    checkedChildren="C/Match" 
    unCheckedChildren="S/Match" 
    size="small" 
    checked={checked} 
    onChange={onChangeCheck} />
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137365/discussion-on-answer-by-suso-guardar-estado-de-un-switch-al-salir-del-componente).